# Return NoneType on queryset django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

### Problem :

I am getting an error like this :

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py"
>   in wrapped_view
>     58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in
>   view
>     87.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py"
>   in dispatch
>     474.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py"
>   in handle_exception
>     434.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py"
>   in dispatch
>     471.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py"
>   in list
>     42.         page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in
>   paginate_queryset
>     172.         return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/pagination.py"
>   in paginate_queryset
>     311.         self.count = _get_count(queryset)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/pagination.py"
>   in _get_count
>     54.         return len(queryset)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /api/userprofiles/ Exception Value:
>   object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

### What I am trying to do :

I just want people to get their own profile, when they connect to the **api**, so instead of applying `UserProfile.objects.all` , I thought it would be better if I used `UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)`.

But as you can well see it isn't working, perhaps because `pagination` has some problem cause it is trying to get `len()` but the object it's getting is `NoneType` although I printed the **queryset** just after it's fetched so as to determine whether it really is `NoneType` , but it isn't.

Here's my **UserProfileViewSet** :

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    # queryset = UserProfile.objects.all(user=request.user)
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    pagination_class = LimitTenPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            queryset = self.request.user.profile.all() # UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            print queryset
        except:
            queryset = None
        return queryset   # UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

    @detail_route(renderer_classes=[renderers.JSONRenderer])
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer ( got it almost instantly )

Well, when I was using `UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)` I was getting an object , instead what I needed to get was a **queryset**.

So changed the queryset to `queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)`